# what does "BUGCHECK_STR: APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_AFTER_CALL" mean in windbg !analyze -v output

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg, crash-dumps

I try to analyze the crash dump file by using windbg, and type the extension command to get some basic analysis result "!analyze -v", and get the result as follow:- (I only pasted part of the info here)

```
....
  ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 00000004
Attempt to read from address 00000004

PROCESS_NAME:  tscommand.exe

...

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 010444c2 to 010181e6

FAULTING_THREAD:  00002270

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_AFTER_CALL

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_AFTER_CALL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_AFTER_CALL

STACK_TEXT:  

...
```

What does "BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_AFTER_CALL" mean here? Does it mean the application is fault because of a NULL class pointer after calling a function? I search the net, cannot find anything about APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_READ_AFTER_CALL.

Comment: That's a bugcheck message that I've never seen.

Comment: Well, it probably means you called a class function with a null pointer.  0xc0000005 is an access violation, and the address is 0x00000004.

Answer (score 2):

The "BUGCHECK_STR" is a classification used by Microsoft to "classify" errors, and this one appears to indicate that you have a NULL class pointer - which seems to be correct to me, since the memory read is from address 4, which is a small offset away from the base of a NULL pointer.

Basically, you are having a situation where you are using a pointer to something (I'm not 100% sure it's a class as such), and the pointer is NULL at the point when you dereference it. It is entirely possible that this is caused by a call to a member function, and the debugger can figure that out [by looking at a combination of call-stack, symbols and register values], but it's not unknown for WinDBG to get these things wrong from time to time - it is heuristics, so it's something like "If we have this value here, and that value there and something else matches this range, then it's this group of errors".

If you posted a bit more of the stack/register values at the point of the crash, it would perhaps be possible to figure out a bit more about what went wrong.

What is certain from the combination of error code and extra data with the error is that your code is reading address 4 in memory. Which typically means trying to use the second integer or float in a class/struct that is pointed to by "NULL". I have seen this a fair few times when I've forgotten a "if (ptr != NULL) ... " in my code. Happens to most of us from time to time...

Comment: Looking at the disassembled code of "here is where it's going wrong", it's clearly a struct or class that is passed in that goes wrong. The +4 is the offset of the member variable being accessed, and you can see in the register dump that `eax` is zero. 
 Without understanding the code, I don't know what to suggest as a next step. It may be some structure inside the `ein` that is at fault. `&rc` is just a pointer to a local variable, right?

Comment: No, the address of a local variable, in a normal system (Windows, Linux, MacOS, Symbian, etc) will never be 4.